# Matlab statement is not inside any function error

Tags: matlab, function, image-processing

This is a simple Matlab code that I'm trying to execute.

```
function result = scale(img, value)
    result = value .* img;
end

dolphin = imread('dolphin.png')
imshow(scale(dolphin, 1.5));
```

The error says:

`Error: File: scale.m Line: 5 Column: 1
This statement is not inside any function.
(It follows the END that terminates the definition of the function "scale".)`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: scale is an existing function name in matlab. You should try and make your function name more unique so you don't have overlap with existing functions.

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf,  I've renamed the scale.m file to myFunction.m. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scale.m` is a function M-file because it begins with the keyword `function`. The part up to `end` is the definition of the function. When you call `scale` at the MATLAB command line, it executes the code in the function. The stuff that comes after `end` is not part of the function, and hence cannot be executed.

If you intended to write a script with a private function `scale` that you want to use only within this script, then put the lines of code that read and display `dolphin` at the top of the file. The private functions should come after the script part. This syntax is supported [since MATLAB R2016b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html).

Otherwise, move the `dolphin` code to a different M-file, which would be a simple script M-file without any function definitions. This script can then use `scale`, which would call the function in the file `scale.m`.

A third alternative, keeping all code in the same file, is to not use a script at all, and put the script code inside a function:

```
function f % just a random name
   dolphin = imread('dolphin.png')
   imshow(scale(dolphin, 1.5));
end

function result = scale(img, value)
   result = value .* img;
end
```

(The function name doesn't need to match the file name, although the MATLAB editor will warn you if these names don't match.)

Comment: I've moved the `dolphin` and `imshow` part on the top. Now the error says, `Error: File: scale.m Line: 4 Column: 7
Function definitions are not permitted in this context.`

Comment: @opu웃: Are you using an older version of MATLAB? If so, you'll have to do the second alternative: one file for the script part, one file for the function. Or make the script into a function (i.e. add `function f` to the top of the file, then write the `dolphin` lines, then `end`, then the `scale` function at the bottom).

Comment: I've moved the `dophin` and `imshow` part to another m file. And it worked! I am using `Matlab R2016a`.

Comment: The third alternative doesn't work for me. The error says, `Error: File: scale.m Line: 6 Column: 19
Function with duplicate name "scale" cannot be defined.`

Comment: @opu웃: Interesting, I had not thought MATLAB would do that. MATLAB's confusion comes, I presume, from the file and the private function having the same name. If so, renaming the file or renaming the function would fix it.

Comment: Wow! Renaming the function has perfectly worked for me!